# Unique results with mysql inner join

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to list posts belonging to several categories in a wordpress mysql database.

The statement I am using is as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_term_relationships
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (12,18,19,20,4161,4157,4160,4168,4183,4185,4188,4190,4192,4195,4199,4200,4202,4205,4332)
AND wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
```

The problem is that some posts are assigned to multiple categories and I get a bunch of duplicates in the results. How do I get only unique posts. In other words, if a post has been assigned to multiple categories, I need it to be listed only once under any of the category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your sql just the fields you need to show alongside with the `DISTINCT` statement, also adjust your join statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT wptr.object_id, 
                wptr.someOtherFields, 
                wp.anotherfield 
  FROM wp_term_relationships wptr
            INNER JOIN wp_posts wp ON wptr.object_id = wp.ID
 WHERE wptr.term_taxonomy_id IN (12, 18, 19, 20, 4161, 4157, 4160, 
                                 4168, 4183, 4185, 4188, 4190, 4192, 
                                 4195, 4199, 4200, 4202, 4205, 4332)
   AND wp.post_status = 'publish'
```

Adding the `DISTINCT` clause will itself eliminate the duplicates. Specify the fields is a good pratice.